# How to pass props from blade to event bus in vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

How would I pass props created in a Laravel blade to the event bus in vuejs? To clarify here is where the blade initially calls the vue component:

```php
<div id="app">
    <home-component
    @if(auth()->check())
        :loggedinuser={{ auth()->user()->id }}
        pusherkey={{ Config::get('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key') }}
        pushercluster={{ Config::get('broadcasting.connections.pusher.options.cluster') }}
    @endif
    />
</div>
```

Here is the home component where I will ultimately be putting the vue router, in place of the video-chat component I have now, which will need the props (I am planning to call them from the bus):

```php
<template>
    <div>
        <top-navbar />
        <div class="row pl-3">
            <div class="col-10 videoWindow px-0">
                <div class="video">                   
                    <video-chat
                    :pusherkey="pusherkey"
                    :pushercluster="pushercluster"
                    :loggedinuser="loggedinuser"
                    ></video-chat>
                </div>
            </div>            
            <sidebar />            
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import CoachNavbar from '../Navbars/CoachNavbar.vue'
import TopNavbar from '../Navbars/TopNavbar.vue'
import VideoChat from '../components/coach/VideoChatCarer.vue'
import sidebar from '../Navbars/CoachNavbar.vue'
export default {
    props: ['loggedinuser', 'pusherkey', 'pushercluster'],
    components: {
        'coach-navbar': CoachNavbar,
        'top-navbar' : TopNavbar,
        'video-chat': VideoChat,
        'sidebar': sidebar
    }, 
    data() {
        return {           
          
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How can I emit the props to the bus if I'm not actively calling a method please? Or failing that if it can't be done, how best do I pass the props from the home component called in the blade to vue router please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a watcher for each prop and emit on update of the prop.

```
watch: { 
    loggedinuser: function(newVal, oldVal) {
       this.$emit('logged-user-changed', newVal);
    },

    anotherprop: function(newVal, oldVal) {
       this.$emit(...);
    },

    ...

}
```

and then catching the event on your component and calling the function on your event bus.

```
<home-component
   @if(auth()->check())
        :loggedinuser={{ auth()->user()->id }}
        pusherkey={{ Config::get('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key') }}
        pushercluster={{ Config::get('broadcasting.connections.pusher.options.cluster') }}
   @endif

   @logged-user-changed="myFunction()"

/>
```

Read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for more information on watchers.

Comment: Ok this does look good but sorry for being dumb but what then goes in my eventBus.js file?